# Solve for the upper limit of integral

Tags: matlab, integral

I am trying to solve for x in the following equation:
[image: Integral Formula]

Where I am trying to solve for x but the integral is too big to do by hand.
This is my attempt in MatLab

```
clc
clear all
close all
syms x t
eqn = (1-(1/(1.3*10^12))*int((t*15)*exp(-t),0,16*x)) == 10^(-4)
sol = solve(eqn,x)
```

this is the result that I got [image: result]. The correct number should be approximately 2.2.  I am very thankful for your help.

Comment: I think maybe this question belongs on math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I already posted there and they think it would be more appropriate if I post here instead.

Comment: You should add the matlab tag and also include whatever output matlab is giving for this. What exactly gets output when you run this?

Comment: Is the term `1.3e-12` exact, or is it something like `1.3077e-12` (factorial of `16`)? In any case, your integral is an [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), so you can use the [`gammaincinv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gammaincinv.html) function to obtain the solution in a single line

Comment: Yes, this is the original equation [link](https://imgur.com/a/7syn3cb). I transformed for easier calculation. In MatLab the lower gammainc function also include the fraction 1 over gamma, however other sites does not include this. I wonder which is correct for the case ?. I am also still a bit confused about the gammaincinv because x is symbolic and gammainc and gammaincinv does not accept symbol. Thanks for your help